# sql sub query to display a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a sub query to display the result of accepted transactions and failed transaction can any one guide me on how to do this ?
this is my query:

```
SELECT ah.MCH_Code,mch.MCH_Name,SUM(isnull(cast(RB.PurchasesPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.capturesPassed as decimal),0))    
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidPurchasePassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.creditPassed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCreditPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCapturesPassed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.authPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidAuthPassed as decimal),0)) as 'Passed Transactions',
    SUM(isnull(cast(RB.PurchasesFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.capturesFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidPurchaseFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.creditFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCreditFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCapturesFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.authFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidAuthFailed as decimal),0)) as 'Failed Transactions'
  FROM PSP.dbo.MCH_AccountHolder AH 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [PSP].[dbo].[RECBUILD] RB ON rb.merchantId = ah.MCH_Code
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PSP.dbo.USERS U on ah.UserId = u.USER_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PSP.dbo.MERCHANTS mch  ON mch.MCH_Code = ah.MCH_Code
  where u.USER_ID = '14655' 
  Group by ah.MCH_Code, u.USER_NAME,mch.MCH_Name
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL, but the code looks like SQL Server.

Comment: Sample data (DDL+DML) and desired results, please.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?  By converting your original query to CTE (basically a subquery that has been moved outside the main query structure to improve readability), it is easy to make use of your computed values in other expressions.  This outputs the same rowset but has the percentage of passed transactions to all transactions included in your the results.

```
;With Totals as
(
SELECT ah.MCH_Code,mch.MCH_Name,SUM(isnull(cast(RB.PurchasesPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.capturesPassed as decimal),0))    
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidPurchasePassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.creditPassed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCreditPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCapturesPassed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.authPassed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidAuthPassed as decimal),0)) as 'Passed Transactions',
    SUM(isnull(cast(RB.PurchasesFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.capturesFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidPurchaseFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.creditFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCreditFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidCapturesFailed as decimal),0))
    +SUM(isnull(cast(RB.authFailed as decimal),0))+SUM(isnull(cast(RB.voidAuthFailed as decimal),0)) as 'Failed Transactions'
  FROM PSP.dbo.MCH_AccountHolder AH 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [PSP].[dbo].[RECBUILD] RB ON rb.merchantId = ah.MCH_Code
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PSP.dbo.USERS U on ah.UserId = u.USER_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PSP.dbo.MERCHANTS mch  ON mch.MCH_Code = ah.MCH_Code
  where u.USER_ID = '14655' 
  Group by ah.MCH_Code, u.USER_NAME,mch.MCH_Name
 )

SELECT *, Passed Transactions / (Passed Transactions + Failed Transactions) as PctPassed
FROM Totals
```